# How to disable git push when there are TODOs in code?

Tags: git, push, todo

We are having an issue in our team and we have decided to check if there is a way or git command to reject git push where there are TODOs in the code.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [how to create git pre hook for detecting 'TODO' or any certain string in commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509455/how-to-create-git-pre-hook-for-detecting-todo-or-any-certain-string-in-commit)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT:** because of grep behaviour in if statement we needed to edit our script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in `git diff --name-only --cached`; do
    grep 'TODO' $FILE 2>&1 >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $FILE ' contains TODO'
        exit 1
    fi
done
exit
```

Is not possible use pre-receive hooks in github, so we are using instead pre-commit hook in client side:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks

Our pre-commit script (based on http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes) looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in `git diff-index -p -M --name-status HEAD -- | cut -c3-` ; do
    if [ "grep 'TODO' $FILE" ]
    then
        echo $FILE ' contains TODO'
        exit 1
    fi
done
exit
```

We have this script under our control version system, and create a symbolic link to it in .git/hooks

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` after creating the file

Comment: Note that this pre-commit hook will complain even for TODOs that were already in the file (i.e. were committed earlier). This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Pre-receive hook on the server, grep the files and abort the push :)

More info on the pre-receive hook can be found here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks

Comment: Any ideas or link where to read about this working in github? Our project is hosted on github and I only see the post-receive hook :?
Of course we can use client-side hooks (like the pre-commit hook), but then we need to create it in all our machines.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

*Old question, but anyway... update for 2023.*

As of 2023, git offers a **pre-push hook**, which does exactly what the question asks. Instead of using a pre-commit hook, as in hosseio's answer, which interferes with committing TODOs, the pre-push hook will let you freely commit and rebase TODOs in the code, and will only prevent pushing them.

Example pre-push hook:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Pre-push hook to prevent pushing code with TODOs.

zero=$(git hash-object --stdin </dev/null | tr '[0-9a-f]' '0')

while read local_ref local_oid remote_ref remote_oid; do
    if test "$remote_oid" = "$zero"; then
        # New branch, examine all commits
        range="$local_oid"
    else
        # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
        range="$remote_oid..$local_oid"
    fi

    # Check for WIP commit
    commit=$(git log --oneline -STODO "$range")
    if test -n "$commit"
    then
            echo >&2 "Found TODO commit, not pushing:"
            echo >&2 "$commit"
            exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Remarks:

- As I could not find a quick, convenient way to check the contents of commits, I used `git log -S` to find commits containing "TODO". This means that the hook will also reject commits that *remove* TODOs - probably not what you want. Of course, if you never push TODOs, you will never need to remove them. Otherwise, just push with `--no-verify`.
- On the other hand, in contrast to the hook from hosseio's answer, this hook *will* allow changing and pushing files with *existing* TODOs, as long as no new TODOs are added (or removed, see above). Whether that is right or wrong is a matter of definition.
- Since the hook checks every commit being pushed, it will also trigger if you push the result of a merge and some commit being merged contains TODOs. This is arguably correct, but may be confusing if you did not author the commit yourself.